# Durandal ko mapping : mapped li not rendered in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, durandal, ko.observablearray

I'm new with durandal. I was trying to add a new module into the demo app provided by durandal using mimosa skelton.

I created the module followings steps in [this](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-View/)

When I run the app `<li>` associated with data-bind is not populated in the DOM. ie., no data is shown in the page.

But when I used console.log to print data inside myPage.js its giving the required output.

my module backend.js

```
define(function(require){
  return {
    getCustomers:function(){
      //do some ajax and return a promise
        return $.ajax({
          url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?',
          dataType: 'json',
        }).promise();
    }
  };
});
```

my myPage.js

```
define(function (require) {
    var backend = require('backend');
    var ko = require('knockout');

    return {
        customer:ko.observableArray([]),
        activate:function(){
          var that = this;
          return backend.getCustomers().then(function(result){
            that.customer(result);
          });
        }
      };
});
```

myPage.html

```
<div>
  <h2>FB Page Detail</h2>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: customer">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

result obtained

```
{"about":"Facebook's mission is to give people the power to share and make the world more open and connected.","category":"Product/service","company_overview":"Newsroom: http://newsroom.fb.com\nInvestor Relations: http://investor.fb.com/","founded":"February 4, 2004","is_published":true,"talking_about_count":207120,"username":"facebook","website":"http://www.facebook.com/facebook","were_here_count":0,"id":"20531316728","name":"Facebook","link":"http://www.facebook.com/facebook","likes":96174118,"cover":{"cover_id":"10151496277356729","source":"http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/s720x720/247388_10151496277356729_2043388331_n.jpg","offset_y":0,"offset_x":0}}
```

What did I do wrong? How to fix this issue?

Comment: what you have here is object not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem here is about how you are using knockoutJS not durandal .. You are passing `object`(single object) to your `observableArray` .. While you should pass array of objects or array of one object..

I have made simple ***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ISozEyU/1/edit)*** to reproduce your issue..

Notice there is no results are displayed, but if you put *magic* `[]` around your data to be array of single object you 'll get `Facebook` name displayed

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you applied bindings here, you may need to use   because your model is set to customer property in the view model.
  `data-bind="html:customer.name"`

Comment: how your response looks like form the server ? in `that.customer(result);` how the result is look like?

Comment: `result` is  an array ?

Comment: Object {about: "Facebook's mission is to give people the power to share and make the world more open and connected.", category: "Product/service", company_overview: "Newsroom: http://newsroom.fb.com↵Investor Relations: http://investor.fb.com/", founded: "February 4, 2004", is_published: true…}